# How to have an object output a default value

Tags: python

I have a class called `myClass`.

```py
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

I have a variable which is an instance of `myClass`

```py
myObject = myClass(5, 3)
```

How do I have it so that when I call `myObject`, it returns a set value instead of `<__main__.myClass object at 0x100816580>`.

For example,

```py
>>> myObject
"some value"
```

Comment: set value of what?

Comment: a string for example

Comment: what string though.

Comment: "hello, world!"

Comment: Are you telling us that when you `print()` an instance it displays: `<__main__.myClass object at 0x100816580>` and you want something else to display?

Comment: lmao ok I didn't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) dunder method:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'some string'

myObject = myClass(5, 3)
print(myObject)
```

Output:

```
some string
```

The [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) dunder method would work too. See [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/13552470)

Comment: fabulous stuff sir